# py2neo - cannot change bolt port

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Although changed bolt port using:

```
authenticate(bolt_url_strippted + ":24786", username, password)
g = Graph(
          host=bolt_url_strippted,
          bolt=True,
          bolt_port=24786,
          user=username,
          password=password)
g.begin()
```

I get the following error:

```
py2neo.packages.neo4j.v1.exceptions.ProtocolError: Unable to connect to <server>.dbs.graphenedb.com on port 7687 - is the server running?
```

I have successful connected to the server using a different python driver with the custom port.
I am using py2neo ver 3.1.2, Neo4j version 3.0.8 via GrapheneDB

edit - the official python-neo4j driver worked for me and the url is of the form: 
'bolt://hobby-XXX.dbs.graphenedb.com:24786'

Thanks,

SK

Comment: Does you bolt URL look something like this 'bolt://x.x.x.x'

Comment: Yes, it is 'bolt://hobby-XXX.dbs.graphenedb.com:24786'. I have a valid connection to the db using the official python neo4j driver using bolt with the exact url and port.

Answer (score 1):

you set **bolt** as False:

> graph = Graph("http://localhost:5687/db/data/", **bolt=False**)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you see the `neo4j.conf` file, there you will find something like this

```
Bolt connector dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level=OPTIONAL
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:24786
```

If your neo4j was running , save this file and restart the database, it will take your port number.
Hope this helps.